# Why is all static typing not inferred?

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, static-typing, inferred-type

As Python supports type annotations, it enables a static typing discipline. When working with the AST produced by the `ast` module, it strikes me that given such discipline all types could be inferred, there should be no need for type annotations. Given a static typing pragma (perhaps a comment at top of the code file), an additional layer of logic in the parser could traverse the AST to determine types of all variables.

For example, take this snippet of code from the [Mypy website](http://mypy-lang.org/examples.html):

```
d = {}  # type: Dict[str, int]

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for s in f:
        for word in re.sub('\W', ' ', s).split():
            d[word] = d.get(word, 0) + 1
```

The dict `d` and its keys and values are typed with a comment, but the type could be inferred from the looping that follows: `s` is a `str` if it is in `f`, the content read from a file; and the dict item value is an `int` because that's what the assignment expression returns.

Is it the case that performing such analysis of the code is generally too expensive for static typing to be inferred, or am I missing something else?

Please note that this question does not relate to the discussion regarding dynamic versus static typing, or optional typing. My point is about type inferrence when the programmer agrees to static typing.

Comment: Here's a difficult case: in the code `x = eval(input("Enter any value:"))`, what is the type of x?

Comment: @Kevin Could be EvalOutput object wrapping all other types `eval` could produce. I mean, where there is a will, there is a way. Drawing attention to such edge cases with zero discussion of the topic presented, is that really meant to be helpful? I have since learnt that what my question refers to is called "structured typing" as opposed to "nominal". So the idea is not new and the question not unreasonable. Particularly in the context of a language like Python, where it's understandable a user may like to have static typing without annotations, given how the language has been used hitherto.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question, too :-) eval is rare enough in production-quality code that it's still worth asking whether static type analysis could be done if we ignore programs containing eval, or declare that it returns an EvalOutput, or whatever. My previous comment is intended to be thought-provoking, rather than discussion-ending. Another open-ended question: what should the type analyzer do with `y = random.choice([1, "foo"])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that type annotations are optional. Indeed, the `re` module has no type annotations, not even in Python 3.8 it would seem. Sure, the analyser could introspect the Python code to see what's going on. However, for some code (like the `re` module), the code eventually dips into the C-API (in CPYthon). At this point the analyser has no way to figure out what the type signature of the function is. As humans, we can read the documentation and know that `re.sub` always returns an instance of `str`, but automated tools have no way of knowing unless they are provided with supplementary type information.

Then you have the problem that some functions return type unions. eg. the `**` operator (`int.__pow__`) that returns an `int`, a `float`, or a `complex` depending on the types **and values** of its operands. eg.

```
>>> 3 ** 2
9
>>> 3 ** -2
0.1111111111111111
>>> 2 ** 0.5
1.4142135623730951
>>> (-1) ** 0.5
(6.123233995736766e-17+1j) # should really just be 1j
```

This means that, given:

```
def f(x: int, y: int):
   z = x ** y
```

`z` would be assigned the type of `object` (the common base of `int`, `float` and `complex`), which is likely not what is desired. By giving the variable a type annotation, we can enable mypy to do type checking when assigning to `z` the result of `x ** y`, but that any future operations on `z` can safely assume the type of `z` to be whatever it was defined to be.